# rails add lib to eager_load_paths without specify directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I found that autoload_paths cause circular dependency in production, so i put lib to eager_load_paths.

`config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")`

But i have a active_record template file, which path is `"#{Rails.root}/templates/active_record/model/model.rb"`

```
<% module_namespacing do -%>
class <%= class_name %> < <%= parent_class_name.classify %>
# accessors .................................................................
# extends ...................................................................
# includes ..................................................................
# relationships .............................................................
<% attributes.select(&:reference?).each do |attribute| -%>
  belongs_to :<%= attribute.name %><%= ', polymorphic: true' if attribute.polymorphic? %>
<% end -%>
# validations ...............................................................
# callbacks .................................................................
# scopes ....................................................................
# additional config .........................................................
<% if attributes.any?(&:password_digest?) -%>
  has_secure_password
<% end -%>
# class methods .............................................................
# public instance methods ...................................................
# protected instance methods ................................................
# private instance methods ..................................................
end
<% end -%>
```

Puma thinks it's a ruby file, so raise a syntax error when starting.

So, how to eager load lib path without specify directory?

Comment: Shouldn't that file be an `.erb`?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb

Answer (score 0):

I fixed its problem after upgrade rails from `4.2.3` to `4.2.4`, and add 
`config.paths.add "lib", glob: "**/*.{rb,yml}", eager_load: true` to config file.